# DDX_Control and DDX_Check is crashing

Tags: c++, mfc

I am writing a MFC application and it is crashing because of below code

```
DDX_Check(pDX, IDC_BTN_TIMEDECAY, m_TimeDecayFlag);
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BTN_TIMEDECAY, m_BtnTimeDecay);
```

IDC_BTN_TIMEDECAY is resource id of CheckBox control.
    m_TimeDecayFlag is BOOL and m_BtnTimeDecay is CMFCButton.

Can someone suggest me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Is `m_TimeDecayFlag` a `bool` or `BOOL`?  `BOOL` is typedef'd to `int` which is what is expected by DDX_Check

Comment: it is BOOL, sorry for confusion

Comment: Does it work if you don't use `DDX_Check`?  You can get the value through `m_BtnTimeDecay.IsChecked()` instead.  I'm not sure it's a problem, but would be wary of binding to multiple controls.  Also, what you have does not crash on my machine (but does NOT work either with both DDX_Check and DDX_Control enabled)

Comment: Yes it does work if I dont use DDX_Check, I have modified my code to use m_BtnTimeDecay.IsChecked() and it works fine. I was just wondering the reason behind this crash

Comment: Is your dialog loaded, and does it have controls with those IDs?

Comment: Have you debugged into the calls to DDX_Check and DDX_Control?

Comment: Are your control IDs inside the valid range? Check TN020: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2zechd4.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Very informative article. But in my care IDs are in valid range!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have ID duplicates. I'm guessing that you will find the value of `IDC_BTN_TIMEDECAY` for some other `ID`.